# update fullCalendar( ‘getDate’ ) regularly

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I need to update a moment variable like

```html
var moment = calendar.fullCalendar('getDate');
```

regularly by using setInterval function but that doesn't have any effect and the moment variable is always the same. Is there a method to have the current moment updated each X seconds ?

thanks,

Comment: Could you post the code that isn't working, including the setInterval function?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I've misunderstood, but it's not really clear why you want to use fullCalendar's getDate function. This will return the date currently selected in fullCalendar. Updating that every few seconds wouldn't be much use - it'll only change whenever the user selects a new date.

If you want to report the actual current time, you can do it easily using momentJS directly, something like this:

```js
var m;

function currentTime() {
  m = moment();
  console.log(m.toISOString());
}

setInterval(currentTime, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I’m doing a project with full calendar and I want to launch some actions at the start of the events and for that I’m comparing the starting moment of the event with the current moment. It looks that the timezone used to calculate full calendar moments is not the same ?

Comment: Not the same as what? It would help if you could explain what precisely you mean. Maybe a specific example of your issue would help. (If you'd like to clarify, please edit the information into your main question and then tag me in a comment, don't place your explanation in here - thanks). fullCalendar does have a concept of timezones, and of ambiguously-zoned moments as well. Have you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone ?